# How can add Contact-Us-form in custom place of page.html.twig file?

Tags: theming, forms, 8, emails

I need to add contact-us form in the custom place of page.html.twig file in my themplate, I want to add some code like belove:

```
<div class="Contact-Us">
    <p>Contact Us</p>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in four steps:

1. Build a contact form.
2. Put this contact form in a block with [Contact Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_block).
3. In block layout put the block in a region -> `myregion`.
4. Place the region in page.html.twig -> `{{ page.myregion }}`